# What's wrong with this "order-preserving MAC" function?

Tags: hash, random-number-generator

<sub>Please note: this is purely a thought experiment and not intended for any real-world usage!</sub>

I came up with a simple function $\mathrm{OPF}$ to map the integers $[0,C)$ (where $C$ is the "ChunkSize") to $512$-bit hashes such that for any $(a, b)$
$$a < b\iff \mathrm{OPF}(a) < \mathrm{OPF}(b)$$
I'm wondering why this is not as secure as existing schemes out there.

The idea is to choose a random point under a certain minimum 512-bit integer $m$ (the `MinVal`), and map the numbers $[0, C)$ into $[m,M]$, where $M=16^{128}-1$ (the `MaxVal`) is the largest integer that can fit in 512-bits. For performance reasons, I arbitrarily chose $m = 5 * 10^{150}$. With these values in hand, we calculate the `StepSize` $s = (M - m) / C$.

The method then relies on 3 procedures, shown below in pseudo-code:

```
keyGen procedure:
  S = <input random secret>
  while true
    R = random_bytes
    hmac = HMAC(S, R)
    break if hmac < StartVal
  return hmac

encodeNumber procedure:
  K = <output from keyGen>
  N = <number in 0..4095>
  start = K + StepSize * N
  while true
    R = random_bytes
    hmac = HMAC(K, R)
    break if hmac > start and (hmac - start) < StepSize
  return hmac
```

(Interestingly, this method can give false positive for equality, but only for adjacent integers and only with 0.5 probability.) This can easily be shown from the code below:

```
equalTo procedure:
  a, b = <encoded numbers> 
  abs(a - b) / StepSize < 1
```

---

Obviously, this scheme is not very "elegant", as it relies on "brute-forcing" our way to the correct results. Nevertheless, it seems easy to understand compared to order-preserving encryption schemes out there (keeping in mind that in this scheme, it is not possible to recover the plaintext.) How does it compare in terms of security?

Intuitively, with a secure order preserving function, we should have that

1. No adversary can predict the image of a point with more than with a pre-determined accuracy
2. No adversary can guess the distance between the points (more than with a pre-determined accuracy).

Let's assume, in this case, that the adversary is only allowed to observe the output of the function. That is, the adversary cannot ask for the encryption of a chosen plaintext.

Comment: Additionally, assume that the input random secret to the `keyGen` procedure is kept secret (i.e. the adversary is only allowed to observe the output of the function).

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes - edited accordingly. To the downvoter, care to explain why this is not a good question? I'm asking specifically why this is NOT secure.

Comment: "the adversary is only allowed to observe the output of the function" Are you saying he can't make queries to it, just see the output of values you choose to 'encrypt'? Or is he allowed to run any of your 3 procedures?

Comment: @figlesquidge Thanks! that makes it much clearer and look more professional. Yes, I am implying that the adversary cannot ask for the "encryption" of a chosen plaintext.

Comment: In theory no, but in practice I imagine an attacker could guess a few values (for example if a value is always initialized to 0, and the attacker is allowed to observe values right after they have been initialized). So let's assume the attacker _does_ have known plaintext (but only through "guessing"). I'm not sure how to state that assumption in technical terms.

Comment: Well if given known-plaintext of number $x$, the attacker can simply add $(y-x)*s$ to get an approximation of $F(y)$ that is expected to be quite good.

Comment: From what I see from the pseudocode, it would appear that $OPF(n)/stepsize - n \in \{0,1\}$.  If so, it would appear that the function fails in its goal of "the adversary must not be able to guess the location of the points".

Comment: 1) If there's a key, why is called a hash rather than a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)? 2) In `while R = random_bytes` is `=` a test? If yes, what is `R`? If no, what is the loop condition? 3) Does `0 ≤ H(N) - K - StepSize*N < StepSize` hold for any N? If yes, a single example pair N,H(N) allows to compute N within 1 from H(N) for any N, seemingly contradicting a natural goal of a hash (preimage-resistance); and this gets worse with more example pairs.

Comment: @fgrieu 1) I updated the title - indeed it's a MAC that is used, as shown in the pseudo-code. 2) I updated the pseudo-code to make it clear what this does.

Comment: Now I see where this scheme fails. Any of you guys care to put up your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see from the pseudocode, it would appear that $OPF(n)/stepsize−n \in \{0,1\}$, that is, an attacker can compute $OPF(n)/stepsize$, and rederive $n$ with a maximum error of 1.

It would appear that the function fails in its goal of "the adversary must not be able to guess the location of the points"

Comment: Can this attack be mitigated if the step size is derived from the initial secret, such that it falls within a suitably large random range, and kept away from the adversary?

Comment: You asked about a order preserving *Message Authentication Code*, MACs are assumed to be secure even in chosen text environments; a secret step size would easily be reconstructed if the attacker got one or two valid text/MAC pairs.  And, even if the attacker didn't have any valid text/MAC pairs, we can estimate the size of a secret stepsize, by examining the MACs he does have; if they are all restricted to a small region, stepsize is likely tiny; if they span almost the entire range, stepsize must be large.